# How to find an index of the ArrayList from the starting index in Java?

Tags: java, arraylist, indexof

I want to search for an index of the element in the ArrayList but I want to start searching from starting index different than 0.

I tried like this:

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<String> bricks = new ArrayList<String>(List.of("BBBB","CCCC","DDDD"));
        System.out.println(bricks.subList(1, bricks.size()).indexOf("CCCC"));
    }
}
```

Output:

```
0
```

Expected output:

```
1
```

I want to start searching for "CCCC" in "bricks" from the starting index "1" not from "0"

Comment: `CCCC` is at index 0 in the sublist you search in. The result you get is correct. If you want the result to be 1, search in `bricks`, not in `bricks.subList(1, bricks.size())`.

Comment: That's what you did. The sub-list is the list offset by the index you started at, and `"CCCC"` is at position 0 in that sublist. So you have the index in the sublist, and the index of where you started from in the original list--seems like addition would be sufficient.

Comment: That said: it kind of seems like you're going around in circles and not taking the time to think through what your code is doing. I would **strongly** recommend either stepping through your code with a debugger (possible using some intermediate variables), or "playing computer" with a pen and paper to try to get a better handle on how the code you write relates to the problem you're solving.

Comment: @DaveNewton I know why I got '0' not '1'. That's just a thing I tried and I know why it didn't work

Comment: Then what's the issue? You have enough information to get its position in the original array.

Comment: @DaveNewton The issue is not "How to find an index". The issue is "How to find an index from the starting index". I want to start searching from the given starting index. But someone answered it already (see below)

Comment: Could you include more test cases, because your example doesn't make sense.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what should happen if the item exists before the start index, or does not exist in the list at all? That's a valid test case you should consider, otherwise you will get incorrect results.

Comment: @Ser Yes, it's what I said in my original comment.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl I know it seems pointless but it's just a part of a bigger program

Comment: @Chaosfire In both cases the output should be "-1" or eventually below 0, something to let me know that it wasn't found

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code finds the index *within the sublist*.

To find the index within the original list, add the index used to create the sublist to the result:

```
System.out.println(bricks.subList(1, bricks.size()).indexOf("CCCC") + 1);
```

Some refactoring makes this clearer:

```
public static <T> int indexOfAfter(List<T> list, T item, int from) {
    int result = list.subList(from, list.size()).indexOf(item);
    return result == -1 ? -1 : (from + result);
}
```

Comment: This will produce incorrect result in the case that `item` does not exist in the list at all, or exists before `from`. But, the question does not give enough information how to handle such cases.

Comment: @Chaosfire In both cases I want the program to print "-1" or eventually something below 0

Comment: @ser see edits to method to return -1 for not found.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int startIndex = 1;
        ArrayList<String> bricks = new ArrayList<String>(List.of("BBBB","CCCC","DDDD"));
        int index = bricks.subList(startIndex, bricks.size()).indexOf("CCCC");
        if(index != -1){
            index = index + startIndex;
        }
        System.out.println(index);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own helper:

```
static <T> int indexOf(List<T> list, int offset, T element) {
    for (int i = offset; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (Objects.equals(list.get(i), element)) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Note that this may be inefficient for non-random-access lists like `LinkedList`. It also handles the lower bound differently from the upper bound, but that can be fixed with an additional check.